# DevExpress XtraReport Setting a DateTime Parameter to Today

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I am using DevXpress XtraReport v13.1

I have a dateTime parameter that I would like its default value to be current Day whenever it is used.
When I leave the value of the parameter empty. it is understood by DevExpress as 1/1/0001 !!!

It is important for me because the parameters will be applied as a filter to a database and I require to decrease the probability that user can fetch too much data from the database (that may affect the performance)

Anyone have an idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all who gave me hints.
I managed to solve my problem programatically by responding to event : ParameterRequestBeforeShow 
Then the report will be shown with today's date as default value for parameters and user is still allowed to select different date.

```
private void XtraReport1_ParametersRequestBeforeShow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.ParametersRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Parameters["StartIssueDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
            this.Parameters["EndIssueDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

I just did It Like this

```
  public Report()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Parameters[0].Value = DateTime.Today;
        this.Parameters[1].Value = DateTime.Today;
    }
```

the Approach  AbdelRahman Shabana took Fails because the Event fires Again when user Clicks Submit, Just Give A look [Here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q230789)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [discussion with a solution](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B200242) in the DevExpress Support Center.

One of those solutions is to create your parameter as a nullable `DateTime?` but then it is more complicated to bind to the `XRControl`.