# Access stored procedure value within XtraReport

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

In my Form I have this code to open my report on a click of Button:

```
private void btnGroupOther_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    LayoutControl lc = new LayoutControl();
    lc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    DateEdit FirstDate = new DateEdit();
    DateEdit LastDate = new DateEdit();
    lc.AddItem(Resources.firstdate, FirstDate).TextVisible = true;
    lc.AddItem(Resources.seconddate, LastDate).TextVisible = true;
    lc.Height = 70;
    this.Controls.Add(lc);
    this.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
    if (DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraDialog.Show(lc, " ", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        RepProductionGroupOther report = new RepProductionGroupOther();
        report.DataSource = paint.RepProductionGroupOther(Convert.ToDateTime(FirstDate.EditValue).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
            Convert.ToDateTime(LastDate.EditValue).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

        report.ShowRibbonPreviewDialog();
    }
}
```

In my header report I have two `xrLabel`; the first one `txtFirstDate` and the second one `txtLastDate`. I want to show the value of `FirstDate` `DateEdit` control in `txtFirstDate` and the value of `LastDate` `DateEdit` control in `txtLastDate`.

How can I do that, the DataSource of the report is sql stored procedure.
It has two Parameters: `@FirstDate` and `@LastDate`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go through XtraReport documentation:
[Request and Pass Report Parameter Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/10000/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/shape-report-data/use-report-parameters/request-and-pass-report-parameter-values)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Create a report instance. 
    XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();

    // Obtain a parameter and set its value. 
    report.Parameters["parameter1"].Value = 30;

    // Hide the Parameters' UI from end-users (if you did not hide it at design time). 
    report.Parameters["parameter1"].Visible = false;

    // Show the report's print preview depending on your target platform. 
    // ... 
}
```

Check the "Custom Parameter Editors" section in above documentation
Custom editor implementation for parameters varies depending on your application's platform:

- Windows Forms

  In Windows Forms applications, you can provide custom parameter editors in the [XtraReport.ParametersRequestBeforeShow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport.ParametersRequestBeforeShow.event) event handler.

  For a code sample, see [Provide Custom Editors for Report Parameters](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/5110/Create-End-User-Reporting-Applications/WinForms-Reporting/Print-Preview/API-and-Customization/Provide-Custom-Editors-for-Report-Parameters).

Below are similar implementation as you are trying to do.. Check these, hope this will help you resolve the issue.
[How to pass parameters to devexpress XtraReport from combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51570284/how-to-pass-parameters-to-devexpress-xtrareport-from-combobox)
[DevExpress XtraReport Setting a DateTime Parameter to Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635285/devexpress-xtrareport-setting-a-datetime-parameter-to-today)

[Passing parameters to Xtrareports repx file](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T593328/passing-parameters-to-xtrareports-repx-file)

Comment: thanks for your help,but my report run without any problem,I only need a way to show query parameters on xrLabel report,i found this article on devexpress but i cannot find a way to implement it in my code: https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/17387/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/shape-report-data/use-report-parameters/query-parameters

Comment: thank you very much Mr Niranjan Singh the first link https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/10000/detailed-guide-to-devexpress-reporting/shape-report-data/use-report-parameters/request-and-pass-report-parameter-values helped me a lot you are the best